# nginx error! The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later

Tags: docker, nginx, url, reverse-proxy, centos7

I am trying to configure nginx as a reverse proxy but I am getting the error from the title.

in nginx.conf server block I set:

```
location /site {
    proxy_pass https://docker_application:port;
}
```

It is weird because if I replace the proxy_pass with an external url like (https://github.com) it works perfectly as I expect. Only wont work with the url of the application in docker container. This docker application can be successfully accessed in the browser. It is like (https://mydomain:9101)

Would appreciate any help

*I know there is a similar question here in stackoverflow but it does not even have an answer.
*It has few information in my question I know, gonna provide any details requested.